# Sorting a match query with ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch to find all records containing a particular string. I'm using a match query for this, and it's working fine.

Now, I'm trying to sort the results based on a particular field. When I try this, I get some very unexpected output, and none of the records even contain my initial search query.

My request is structured as follows:

```
{
"query": 
{
    "match": {"_all": "some_search_string"}
 },
 "sort": [
 {
    "some_field": {
        "order": "asc"
        }
 }
 ] }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort on a string field, your mapping must contain a non-analyzed version of this field. [Here's a simple blog post I found](http://awesomism.co.uk/sorting-string-fields-with-elasticsearch/) that describes how you can do this using [the multi_field mapping type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's the issue. If I search for a particular term instead of using the match query, the sorting works just fine. For eg, if I try: 
"query": { 
"term": {"some_field": "some_Search_String"}
}, 

the sorting works out.

Is there some issue while using the sort feature with match in particular?
I appreciate the help!

Comment: The provided link is not working anymore.